# R:: stringr: str_replace_all the " | " symbol

Tags: r, replace, stringr, gsub

```
x = c("a | b", "a b", "a,  b", "a,b", "a.b")

str_replace_all(x, "  |  ", ", ")
```

the desired output is:

```
"a, b", "a b", "a,  b", "a,b", "a.b"
```

but I'm not sure how to keep stringr (or gsub) from thinking its the "or" operator instead of an annoying character I'm trying to clean up from my dataset.

Comment: You either need to escape the special character with two backslashes, or  (more efficiently) since you are doing a direct, exact replacement, not using any regex pattern matching, you can indicate that your pattern is **fixed**, either by using the `fixed = TRUE` argument of `sub` or `gsub` or wrapping your pattern in `stringr::fixed()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `|` (which is a regex metacharacter signifying alternation):

```
str_replace_all(x, " \\|", ",")
[1] "a, b"  "a b"   "a,  b" "a,b"   "a.b"
```